# ReferenceError when using third-party library for cloud code in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to include underscore.js in my parse cloud code as below

```
require('cloud/underscore.js');
```

And this is the code that use its function

```
var uniqTest = _.uniq([1,5,4,4,5,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1]);
response.success(uniqTest);
```

But it's giving me following response

```
{
"code": 141,
"error": "ReferenceError: _ is not defined\n    at main.js:146:20"
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: it looks like the variable _ is not present or assigned. var _ = require ... Or did you do the assignment at a different place in code?

Comment: It point to error where  _.uniq([1,5,4,4,5,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1]) is defined.

Comment: you try to execute uniq on _ and since _ seems not to be defined _.uniq will not work. Try to do var _ = require('cloud/underscore.js');

Comment: Thank u now it's working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more obvious for others and to give you a chance to mark this as answered :)

It looks like the variable `_` is not assigned.
You try to execute uniq on `_` and since `_` seems not to be defined `_.uniq` will not work. Try to do `var _ = require('cloud/underscore.js');`